# R Markdown fig.cap repeats citation

Tags: r, r-markdown, fig

I am trying to create a figure legend. My figure caption is quite long, so I'm referencing it as part of the text.

Here is the section of the R Markdown:

---

A reference to the figure in the text (See Figure @ref(fig:fig))

````
    ```{r fig, fig.cap="(ref:fig)"}
    fig
    ```
````

(ref:fig) This legend describes the plot "fig".

---

When knitted, this should look like the following:

A reference to the figure in the text (See Figure 1)

**an image of the figure here**

Figure 1: This legend describes the plot "fig".

---

However, instead I get:

A reference to the figure in the text (See Figure 1)

**an image of the figure here**

Figure 1: (ref:fig)

(ref:fig) This legend describes the plot "fig".

---

I'm not sure why it's repeating "(ref:fig)" even though it recognises it as Figure 1. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with your YAML. Numbered figure caption is an output from [Bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-number.html). To use it you have to change the YAML to

```
---
title: A title
output:
   bookdown::html_document2: default
---
```

The YAML above will give you the results you are after.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. Unfortunately, that is the set-up for my YAML header currently so I'm still unsure how to fix the problem

Comment: Do you have it exactly like on my answer or you have `html_document: df_print: paged` on the top of `bookdown::html_document2: default`? Because if you have it as the latter, you will be generating a regular HTML, and the output will be what you are getting. In this case you have to choose to knit to `html_document2`

Comment: No, mine is exactly like in your answer.